# OLRE's vs. Beta Binomial Model for Overdispersed Mixed Effect logistic regression with proportion data?

Tags: mixed-model, lme4-nlme, diagnostic, beta-binomial-distribution, glmmtmb

this is a long post, as I wanted to be sure to provide all relevant information regarding my data, model, the methods that I have tried so far, and my diagnostic plots. If there are ways I should simplify, please let me know and I will edit for brevity.

I am using `lme4::glmer()` to fit a binomial generalized linear mixed model with a dependent variable that is proportional rather than binary. My response variable ranges from 0 to 1, with many 0’s and a good number of  1’s as well (see distribution below).
[image]

**Data Information:** 
Briefly, these data represent behavioral observations from 14 individuals. Each individual was observed at 5 minute intervals for multiple days, with observations averaged over 2 hour periods. The response variable is the proportion of observations in each 2 hour period that the individual being observed was performing a behavior of interest, while the predictor variables are treatment (a factor with 2 levels) and temperature (average temperature for that 2 hour period, scaled using the scale function to help with model convergence). The overall goal is to determine whether an experimental treatment influences the relationship between temperature and the proportion time spent performing of the behavior of interest.

**Initial Model and Diagnostics:**

```
M1 <- glmer(BehaviorProp ~ TemperatureS * Treatment + (TemperatureS | Individual), 
            data = birds, family = binomial(), weights = BehaviorCount)
```

I am using the DHARMa package to perform model diagnostics (see below). The diagnostic plots for this initial model indicate that the residuals are not uniformly distributed, that I have many outliers, overdispersion, and zero inflation. Given that logistic regression does not assume normally distributed residuals and that 0’s are an expected response, I am not sure if I need to be worried about the residual Q-Q plot or the zero inflation plot (if this is incorrect, please let me know!). However, I am concerned about the over dispersion. 
[image]
[image]
[image]

**My overall question is: What would be the best way to model my data to take care of the overdispersion?** Below, I have outlined the methods that I have tried so far (beta-binomial model with zero inflation, binomial model with OLRE). The diagnostic plots for the model with OLRE (included below) look much better than those for the beta-binomial model with zero inflation (also included below); however, I am not sure how much to rely on these plots for comparison, given that the DHARMa package may not be able to appropriately simulate residuals from the beta-binomial model. I am also not sure if, in using an OLRE rather than beta-binomial, I would be falling into the pitfalls outlined in [this model by Xavier Harrison](https://peerj.com/articles/1114/).

Being a relative beginner to statistics, I am not sure which of the two methods makes sense for my data. Since I didn’t know which method to use, I have done for both. Model specification and diagnostic plots are below:

**Observation Level Random Effect Model:**

```
M_olre <- glmer(BehaviorProp ~ TemperatureS * Treatment + (TemperatureS | Individual) 
                    + (1 | index), data = birds, family = binomial(), 
                weights = BehaviorCount)
```

This seems to have solved the problem of overdispersion, and the outlier and zero-inflation plots look much better as well. The QQ plot still doesn’t look great, but again I’m not sure if I need to pay attention to that, given that uniformly distributed residuals are not necessarily expected in binary models. 
[image]
[image]
[image]

**Beta Binomial Model:**

```
M_BetaBinom <- glmmTMB(BehaviorProp ~ TemperatureS * CoverType + (TemperatureS | Individual), 
                       data=birds, family=beta_family(), 
                       weights = PantingCount, ziformula = ~.)
```

In order for this model to work, I had to change all of the ‘1’ values in my response variable to 0.999. The diagnostics for this model look much worse than those for the OLRE model, but as stated above, I am not sure how much I can trust these because I don’t know how well the DHARMa package works on this type of mode. When generating the DHARMa graphs, I received the following warnings:

> Model family was recognized or set as continuous, but duplicate values
>   were detected in the response. Consider if you are fitting an
>   appropriate model. Duplicate non-integer values found in the
>   simulation. If this is because you are fitting a non-inter valued
>   discrete response model, note that DHARMa does not perform appropriate
>   randomization for such cases.

[image]
[image]
[image]

**Overall, I am wondering:
Which of these methods make more sense for my data? Is there another method that I have not yet considered that may work better?
I would also gladly accept any input regarding the structure of my models. Do my RE’s make sense? Is the `ziformula` in my beta-binomial model properly specified?**

All input is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is there a reason you're using family=beta_family() and not family=betabinomial for your beta-binomial model ... ??  You shouldn't have to adjust your prop=1.0 values for the beta-binomial, provided the denominators (max possible counts) are properly coded in the `weights` argument ...

Comment: I based the code for the betabinomial model off of the post linked below because I thought that the data seemed similar to mine. After changing my model to family=betabinomial, I got the following error: 


Looking at the suggested vignette, it seems like my ziformula may have been overparamaterized. I changed it to zi~TemperatureS just to simplify (though I'm not sure that was the correct action). I also removed the random slope (so my RE is (1|Individual). The DHARMa plots for that model show severe underdispersion.

Post: https://github.com/glmmTMB/glmmTMB/issues/507

Comment: With regards to the weights argument: I believe I have it structured correctly. Each 2 hour period consists of 24 observations (1 every 5 minutes). Because the data collection method used cameras, some observations that had to be excluded (because the camera got fogged up, temporarily went down, etc.). So for some 2 hour periods, the response variable (proportion of observations in which the animal was exhibiting the behavior of interest) was less than 24. For each data point, the value in the 'BehaviorCount' represents the number of photos that the proportion was calculated from (range=12-24)

Comment: @C.H. The link you gave deals with zero-inflated *beta regression* and **not** with *beta-binomial regression*. As confusing as it is, it is not the same thing. Unless I'm mistaken, *beta regression* (and its extensions: e.g. ZI or ZOIB) is for continuous proportions while *beta-binomial regression* is for count-based proportions that are overdispersed. See: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/481099/beta-vs-beta-binomial-why-beta-has-higher-aic/481104#481104 or https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1111/2041-210X.13234